# ошибка httpError status: 502 jsf

Tags: jsf

Есть сайт работающий в связке: Tomcat + JSF.
Есть страница, которая преобразует **"текст введенный пользователем"** в:
**кавычки** + "текст введенный пользователем" + **кавычки**.

Отовсюду, где нет firewall все работает без проблем, но с работы, где стоит firewall, при вводе фразы "**drop table**", вылетает ошибка:

> httpError: There was an error communicating with the server, status: 502

С чем может быть связано, ведь в том же google поисковике, без проблем ищется фраза "**drop table**".

Comment: Говорят, что правильно заданный вопрос - это уже половина ответа. HTTP Code 502 сообщает о том, что проблема в firewall-е, Вы и сами про это пишете. Соответственно, вопрос не про JSF и Tomcat, а про администрирование сетей. Спросите у системных администраторов на Вашей работе, что не так с "drop table"... Подозреваю, что дело даже не в кавычках, а в содержимом фразы...

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос, почему, к примеру на сайте http://sqlformat.org/ можно свободно ввести эту команду? Я почему подумал про JSF, может какой то обработчик не тот или еще что, ведь на других сайтах нет проблем.

Comment: Ну серьёзно, спросите админов, что просто так гадать? Пусть в логах посмотрят что происходит. Может ограничения не на все сайты работают, а по каким-то правилам. А может, моя догадка насчёт firewall-а вовсе неверна (был бы уверен в её верности, оформил бы как ответ, а не как комментарий)...

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо за очередную подсказку, спрошу у админов.